# Error_Invalid_Parameter Error 57 when calling CreateRemoteThread with Python 3.2 CTypes

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes, dll-injection

I'm trying to perform DLL injection using Python's Ctypes.  I attach Olly to the process that I'm trying to inject and the thread that I'm trying to creates gives the error, "ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER 00000057".  I've been doing some research and I've found that as the error says one of my parameters is bad when I call CreateRemoteThread.  I can't seem to figure out what parameter is bad as all the values that I send in seem valid.  I set an Olly conditional break point on the call to LoadLibrary and the dll name and (full) path are correct.  I also don't see my custom dll loaded in the memory space of the process (in Olly).  I'm wondering if it has to do with the fact that my dll and path are unicode when I send them in as a parameter.  Although the conditional breakpoint on LoadLibrary says the correct name and path.  I also set the argtype and as I understand it an error would be thrown if it was the wrong type and it would try to convert it to the correct type when possible.

```
import sys
from ctypes import *
from ctypes import wintypes
import ctypes

BYTE      = c_ubyte
WORD      = c_ushort
DWORD     = c_ulong
LPBYTE    = POINTER(c_ubyte)
LPTSTR    = POINTER(c_char) 
HANDLE    = c_void_p
PVOID     = c_void_p
LPVOID    = c_void_p
UNIT_PTR  = c_ulong
SIZE_T    = c_ulong
LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE = c_void_p

class SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES(ctypes.Structure):
_fields_ = [("nLength", DWORD),
            ("lpSecurityDescriptor", LPVOID),
            ("bInheritHandle", wintypes.BOOL)]

LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES = POINTER(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)

kernel32.CreateRemoteThread.retype = wintypes.HANDLE
kernel32.CreateRemoteThread.argtypes = [wintypes.HANDLE, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, ctypes.c_size_t, LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE, wintypes.LPVOID, wintypes.DWORD, wintypes.LPDWORD]

pid     = sys.argv[1]
dll_path    = sys.argv[2]  #'myDLL.dll'
dll_len = len(dll_path) * 2 #Multiplied by 2 so it would take into account the unicode characters

h_process = kernel32.OpenProcess( PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, int(pid))
arg_address = kernel32.VirtualAllocEx(h_process, 0, dll_len, VIRTUAL_MEM, PAGE_READWRITE)

written = c_ubyte(0)
bSuccess = kernel32.WriteProcessMemory(h_process, arg_address, dll_path, dll_len, byref(written))
h_kernel32 = kernel32.GetModuleHandleW('kernel32.dll')
h_loadlib = kernel32.GetProcAddress(h_kernel32, b"LoadLibraryW")

thread_id = c_ulong(0)

h_thread = kernel32.CreateRemoteThread(h_process, #404
                                   None, 
                                   0, 
                                   h_loadlib,     #0x770a0000
                                   arg_address,   #0x770eef42
                                   0, 
                                   byref(thread_id))

h_threadError = GetLastError()    #This says ERROR 0 - Operation completed Successfully

h_dllToHook = kernel32.GetModuleHandleW('myDLL.dll')  #h_dllToHook returns '0'
error = GetLastError()            #This says ERORR 0 - Operation completed Successfully
```

Another weird thing is the fact that the executable I'm injected is a console application and prints some stuff out.  The dll that I'm injecting has an exported function that is called from DLLMAIN that prints stuff out as well.  When I check the console it looks like it successfully ran as the stuff in the injected DLL was printed out as well.  Also when I put a conditional logging breakpoint on CreateRemoteThread it never gets hit.  So my questions are if it is successfully injecting as it seems to be 1) why can't I get a handle to the injected DLL using GetModuleHandleW and 2) why isn't Ollydbg showing that the injected DLL isn't mapped into the process' memory space.  I'm stepping through my code and breaking so it's not like the thread is running through and exiting.  I've been researching for a while so any help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

- Use `ctypes.get_last_error` instead of `GetLastError`. This requires the `use_last_error` option, e.g. `WinDLL('kernel32.dll', use_last_error=True)`.
- The `GetModuleHandleW` and `GetProcAddress` steps are unnecessary. ctypes already does this for you. Just use `kernel32.LoadLibraryW`. This depends on kernel32.dll always being mapped to the same base address in each process, which I think is true for existing versions of Windows.
- In general you should factor in the null terminator when copying a string, e.g. use `len(dll_path) + 1`. In this case you're committing a new page of memory (4 KiB on x86 and x64 systems), which is initially all zeros.
- I'm not sure how you've defined the `VIRTUAL_MEM` allocation type. Does that include `MEM_COMMIT`?
- Watch out for spelling errors. You wrote `retype` instead of `restype` for the prototype of `CreateRemoteThread`, which means the return value is still the default 32-bit C `int`.

The following works for me, loading a DLL into a Python process.

**dllinject.py (ctypes defintions):**

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes

kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32.dll', use_last_error=True)

PROCESS_VM_OPERATION = 0x0008
PROCESS_VM_WRITE = 0x0020
PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD = 0x0002
MEM_COMMIT = 0x1000
MEM_RELEASE = 0x8000
PAGE_READWRITE = 0x0004
INFINITE = -1

SIZE_T = ctypes.c_size_t
LPSIZE_T = ctypes.POINTER(SIZE_T)
WCHAR_SIZE = ctypes.sizeof(wintypes.WCHAR)
LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES = wintypes.LPVOID
LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE = wintypes.LPVOID

class BOOL_CHECKED(ctypes._SimpleCData):
    _type_ = "l"
    def _check_retval_(retval):
        if retval == 0:
            raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
        return retval

class LPVOID_CHECKED(ctypes._SimpleCData):
    _type_ = "P"
    def _check_retval_(retval):
        if retval is None:
            raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
        return retval

HANDLE_CHECKED = LPVOID_CHECKED  # not file handles

kernel32.OpenProcess.restype = HANDLE_CHECKED
kernel32.OpenProcess.argtypes = (
    wintypes.DWORD, # dwDesiredAccess
    wintypes.BOOL,  # bInheritHandle
    wintypes.DWORD) # dwProcessId

kernel32.VirtualAllocEx.restype = LPVOID_CHECKED
kernel32.VirtualAllocEx.argtypes = (
    wintypes.HANDLE, # hProcess
    wintypes.LPVOID, # lpAddress
    SIZE_T,          # dwSize
    wintypes.DWORD,  # flAllocationType
    wintypes.DWORD)  # flProtect

kernel32.VirtualFreeEx.argtypes = (
    wintypes.HANDLE, # hProcess
    wintypes.LPVOID, # lpAddress
    SIZE_T,          # dwSize
    wintypes.DWORD)  # dwFreeType

kernel32.WriteProcessMemory.restype = BOOL_CHECKED
kernel32.WriteProcessMemory.argtypes = (
    wintypes.HANDLE,  # hProcess
    wintypes.LPVOID,  # lpBaseAddress
    wintypes.LPCVOID, # lpBuffer
    SIZE_T,           # nSize
    LPSIZE_T)         # lpNumberOfBytesWritten _Out_

kernel32.CreateRemoteThread.restype = HANDLE_CHECKED
kernel32.CreateRemoteThread.argtypes = (
    wintypes.HANDLE,        # hProcess
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,  # lpThreadAttributes
    SIZE_T,                 # dwStackSize
    LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE, # lpStartAddress
    wintypes.LPVOID,        # lpParameter
    wintypes.DWORD,         # dwCreationFlags
    wintypes.LPDWORD)       # lpThreadId _Out_

kernel32.WaitForSingleObject.argtypes = (
    wintypes.HANDLE, # hHandle
    wintypes.DWORD)  # dwMilliseconds

kernel32.CloseHandle.argtypes = (
    wintypes.HANDLE,) # hObject
```

**dllinject.py (`injectdll`):**

```
def injectdll(pid, dllpath):
    size = (len(dllpath) + 1) * WCHAR_SIZE
    hproc = hthrd = addr = None
    try:
        hproc = kernel32.OpenProcess(
            PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION |
            PROCESS_VM_WRITE, False, pid)
        addr = kernel32.VirtualAllocEx(
            hproc, None, size, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE)
        kernel32.WriteProcessMemory(
            hproc, addr, dllpath, size, None)
        hthrd = kernel32.CreateRemoteThread(
            hproc, None, 0, kernel32.LoadLibraryW, addr, 0, None)
        kernel32.WaitForSingleObject(hthrd, INFINITE)
    finally:
        if addr is not None:
            kernel32.VirtualFreeEx(hproc, addr, 0, MEM_RELEASE)
        if hthrd is not None:
            kernel32.CloseHandle(hthrd)
        if hproc is not None:
            kernel32.CloseHandle(hproc)
```

**test.c:**

```
#include <Windows.h>                  
#include <stdio.h>                 

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstDll, DWORD fdwReason, PVOID fImpLoad)
{                                                
    switch (fdwReason) {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            printf("DLL Attach\n");
            break;
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            printf("DLL Detach\n");
    }                                                        
    return TRUE;               
}
```

**demo:**

```
>>> import sys
>>> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
>>> from dllinject import injectdll
>>> cmd = [sys.executable, '-c', 'import time; time.sleep(10)']
>>> p = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE); injectdll(p.pid, 'test.dll')
>>> r = p.wait(); print(p.stdout.read().decode())
DLL Attach
DLL Detach
```