# Code injection on a Windows process

Tags: python, windows, process, code-injection

I was reading up on people who could create scripts to inject code into a Windows process, to make the running process malfunction or function in the way the injector desires. I have also seen that this is called *"DLL injection"*, if I'm not mistaken.

I have been searching around how this is done on Python, and couldn't find a clean answer.

**How is this implemented on Python?** You would need Windows compatibility such as `pywin32` modules, but then what from there? I have seen this done on C, but never on Python. Python was created in C so it should be possible to do this.

Comment: Are you trying to *accomplish* dll injection using python into a binary, or are you trying to inject code change into a python script using DLL injection? The first is quite complex and probably quite impractical as an answer, the second is not really necessary as you can simply modify the python code itself. DLL injection into a python program is definitely the *wrong* thing to be doing; there are far easier mechanisms available in the language itself.

Comment: @Petesh I'm asking from python to inject code to am open process, or python implementing the DLL injection, not the other way around. So yes "Are you trying to accomplish dll injection using python into a binary".

Comment: https://github.com/infodox/python-dll-injection

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17524073/205580), which defines an `injectdll` function. Injecting a DLL into a process is standard practice -- Windows itself does it all the time. A secure process *should* be protected by its security descriptor (DACL ACEs and SACL integrity level) and the assigned desktop with respect to DLL injection and window messages.