# Load a DLL from Python to a Separate Process

Tags: python, dll, ctypes, loadlibrary

I'd like to load a DLL from Python into a process that is not the same as the process running Python. `ctypes.LoadLibrary` says `Load a shared library into the process and return it. This method always returns a new instance of the library.`

What I want is to be able to call something like `LoadLibrary` but load the DLL on a separate process that can then be accessed by numerous other processes without hindering the Python process's operations or the Python process hindering the DLL's operations.
Is that possible through a Python construct? If it's not what are other potential solutions?

I am running Windows 7 with Python 2.7.3

Comment: If you want the DLL to be loaded in a separate Python process, then use either `multiprocessing` or `subprocess`.

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, loading a DLL by itself into another process isn't generally done, except for COM DLLs loaded in a surrogate dllhost.exe process. With COM there's a generic IPC mechanism via LPC/RPC, so this kind of thing makes sense. If your DLL doesn't implement some kind of IPC API, then I'm afraid your question is misguided. You cannot load an arbitrary DLL into a host process and call its functions across process boundaries. Processes are isolated from each other except for IPC mechanisms that go through the kernel (files, pipes, sockets, shared memory, etc).

Comment: Well, most plafforms have a way to inject code into another process (if you have the right privs), which can be a useful thing to do sometimes (especially if the DLL can override symbols, or the equivalent in a higher-level runtime like ObjC's). But ctypes isn't meant for that, and I doubt it's what the OP is trying to do, so...

Comment: @abarnert, to use ctypes to inject a DLL into a process, see `injectdll` in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17524073/205580). But it's not the same as what the OP wants, i.e. "load the DLL on a separate process that can then be accessed by numerous other processes".