# Python GetModuleHandleW OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

Tags: windows, python-3.x, x86-64, ctypes

The following code generates the error :

```
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

```
windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleW.restype = wintypes.HMODULE
windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleW.argtypes = [wintypes.LPCWSTR]
KERNEL32 = windll.GetModuleHandleW("C:\\Windows\\System32\\kernel32.dll")
```

However, if I use

```
KERNEL32 = windll.LoadLibrary("C:\\Windows\\System32\\kernel32.dll")
```

The dll is found but I encounter a different error by the following code:

```
LoadLibAddy = windll.kernel32.GetProcAddress(KERNEL32, "LoadLibraryA")
```

The error generated is :

```
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1:  Don't know how to convert parameter 1
```

I was hoping someone would have an idea on how to fix either of these errors.
The full script:

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes import wintypes

def dllinjector(processID, DLL_NAME):
    KERNEL32 = WinDLL('kernel32.dll', use_last_error=True)
    KERNEL32.GetProcAddress.restype = c_void_p
    KERNEL32.GetProcAddress.argtypes = (wintypes.HMODULE, wintypes.LPCSTR)
    PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD = 0x0002
    PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x0400
    PROCESS_VM_OPERATION = 0x0008
    PROCESS_VM_WRITE = 0x0020
    PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010
    openHandle = KERNEL32.OpenProcess(PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD|
                                             PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION|
                                             PROCESS_VM_OPERATION|
                                             PROCESS_VM_WRITE|
                                             PROCESS_VM_READ, False, processID)
    MEM_RESERVE = 0x00002000
    MEM_COMMIT = 0x00001000
    PAGE_READWRITE = 0x04

    if not openHandle:
        print("OpenProcess failed.")
        print("GetLastError: ", KERNEL32.GetLastError())
        return False
    print("openProcess GetLastError: ", KERNEL32.GetLastError())
    #print("Successfully opened process.")

    LoadLibAddy = KERNEL32.GetProcAddress(KERNEL32._handle, b"LoadLibraryA")
    if not LoadLibAddy:
        raise WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
    print("LoadLibAddy: ", LoadLibAddy)
    print("LoadLibAddy GetLastError: ", KERNEL32.GetLastError())

    # Allocate space in the process for the dll
    RemoteString = KERNEL32.VirtualAllocEx(openHandle, None, len(DLL_NAME), MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE)
    print("RemoteString GetLastError: ", KERNEL32.GetLastError())
    if not RemoteString:
        print("VirtualAllocEx failed.")
        return False

    # Write the string name of the dll in the memory allocated
    if not KERNEL32.WriteProcessMemory(openHandle, RemoteString, DLL_NAME, len(DLL_NAME), None):
        print("WriteProcessMemory failed.")
        return False
    print("WriteProcessMemory GetLastError: ", KERNEL32.GetLastError())

    #Load the dll
    if not KERNEL32.CreateRemoteThread(openHandle, None, None, c_longlong(LoadLibAddy), RemoteString, None, None):
        print("CreateRemoteThread failed.")
        return False
    print("CreateRemotedThread GetLastError: ", windll.kernel32.GetLastError())
    #print("CreateRemoteThread: ", windll.kernel32.CreateRemoteThread(openHandle, None, None, LoadLibAddy, RemoteString, None, None))

    KERNEL32.CloseHandle(openHandle)
    print("CloseHandle GetLastError: ", KERNEL32.GetLastError())

    return True

def main():
    processID = 25408
    DLL_NAME = "mydll32.dll"

    dllinjector(processID, DLL_NAME)

    print("program completed.")

main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleW("kernel32.dll")`. But please don't use `windll` when defining function prototypes because it's global to all modules that use ctypes, which leads to conflicting prototypes. Use `kernel32 = WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)`. The DLL handle is `kernel32._handle`.

For your 2nd problem, first and foremost there's no reason to ever directly call `GetProcAddress` (or `dlsym` on POSIX systems) when using ctypes. But in principle it would be as follows:

```
kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)   
kernel32.GetProcAddress.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
kernel32.GetProcAddress.argtypes = (wintypes.HMODULE, wintypes.LPCSTR)

LoadLibAddy = kernel32.GetProcAddress(kernel32._handle, b'LoadLibraryA')
if not LoadLibAddy:
    raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
```

Note that the function name is passed as `bytes`. Anyway, you don't need this since `kernel32.LoadLibraryA` (or `kernel32.LoadLibraryW`) is a function pointer that you can pass as an argument or cast to `c_void_p`, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! You made my script work. The only problem I have now is understanding the new code as I am finding it a lot more complex than the non-working version. Thanks again!

Comment: If it's relevant you can edit your question to include a more complete example. Then I'll see if there's a way to streamline and simplify what you're trying to do.

Comment: I don't like the idea of having other people code for me as I would rather try and learn on my own. I will edit in the full script for you to look at just in case I am doing something very wrong in it and in case anyone else has a similar problem in the future. The script is mean to inject a DLL into another process.

Comment: Take at look at my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17524073/205580). I tried to set up the ctypes definitions to make the main code in the `injectdll` function readable and reliable.