# GetProcAddress() not working on x64 Python

Tags: python-2.7, ctypes

```
from ctypes import *
kernel32 = windll.kernel32
msvcrt = cdll.msvcrt

def func_resolve(dll, function):
    handle = kernel32.GetModuleHandleA(dll)
    error = kernel32.GetLastError()
    print "%d: %s" % (error, FormatError(error))

    address = kernel32.GetProcAddress(handle, function)
    error = kernel32.GetLastError()
    print "%d: %s" % (error, FormatError(error))

    kernel32.CloseHandle(handle)
    return address

msvcrt.printf("printf\n")
printf_address = func_resolve("msvcrt", "printf")
getmodulehandle_address = func_resolve("kernel32", "getmodulehandlea")
```

This is x64 python. Just trying to get the address of some functions. I use `printf` there just to make sure that `msvcrt` is loaded. When I execute I get this:

```
0: The operation completed successfully.
126: The specified module could not be found.
6: The handle is invalid.
127: The specified procedure could not be found.
printf
```

Why I get a handle for `msvcrt` but not for `kernel32`? And since I have a proper handle, why `GetProcessAdress()` is failing for `printf`? If I execute this with x86 python it works for the `printf` (`kernel32` still fails). Does this mean that ctypes is loading only 32 bit dlls? If so is there a way of loading 64 bit instead?

Comment: See my answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33780664/205580) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17524073/205580).

Comment: @eryksun Thanks for the help, it worked. Why do I have to set the variable types only in 64 bits Python though? And if I print `msvcrt.printf` I get a pointer different than the one from `GetProcAddress()`, why is that?

Comment: The default integer conversion is to and from a 32-bit C int, which happens to be the same size as a pointer in 32-bit Python. As to the address, `msvcrt.printf` is a ctypes function pointer object. Printing shows you the address (i.e. `id`) of the Python object, not the target address. The simplest way to see the function pointer's value is to cast it to a void pointer, e.g. `c_void_p.from_buffer(msvcrt.printf).value`.